# How to align btn-toolbar to right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog, alignment, toolbar

i'm creating the footer of a bootstrap modal and i would align the btn-toolbar to the right of the text.
I tried with the following code:

```
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="text-center alert alert-danger">
      <p>confirm deletation?
        <span class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-flat fa fa-times"></button>
          <button data-dismiss="modal"
                  class="btn btn-success btn-flat fa fa-check"></button>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but i get the following result:

As you can see the button group on the right is not aligned with the text. How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make use of the **inline** class.

Something like this, although you may need to work on the padding:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <div class="btn-toolbar inline pull-right"> 
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-flat inline fa fa-times"></button>
      <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-flat inline fa fa-check"></button>
    </div>
    <p>confirm deletation?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TomBowen89/vsd21thf/2/)

Comment: It is the same result of mine!

Comment: In my answer the text is right-aligned with the buttons. Is this not what you are after?

Comment: @smartmouse looking at your reply to the other answer, are you trying to vertically align the text? In your question you say right-align.

Comment: I want the btn-toolbar on the right and the text vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0):

add this style

```
style="margin-top: -5px;"
```

like this:

```
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="text-center alert alert-danger">
      <p>confirm deletation?
          <span class="btn-toolbar pull-right" style="margin-top: -5px;">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-flat fa fa-times"></button>
          <button data-dismiss="modal"
                  class="btn btn-success btn-flat fa fa-check"></button>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```